# Vue js - not all the data showing after store dispatch

Tags: vue.js, vuex

The select box not showing sometimes the first color and sometimes not showing the first color.
How can i make it to show all the item in the select box?
I'm not getting for some reason all the promises

You can see the issue in the picture
Please help me to fix this issue i'm new to vue js

[image]

My code:

```
data() {
        return {
            propertiesTree: []
  }
}
getPropertyGroups(objectId: number): void {
            if (this.$data.currentObjectId === objectId)
                return;

            let component: any = this;

            this.$data.currentObjectId = objectId;

            component.showLoader();
            this.$store.dispatch('properties/getPropertyGroups', objectId)
                .then(({ data, status }: { data: string | Array<propertiesInterfaces.PropertyGroupDto>, status: number }) => {

                    // console.log(data, "data");
                    // console.log(status, "status")
                    if (status === 500) {
                        this.$message({
                            message: data as string,
                            type: "error"
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        let anyData = data as any;
                        anyData.map(item => {
                            item.properties.map(prop => {
                                if(prop.type.toString() === 'dictionary'){
                                    prop.dictionaryList = [];
                                    prop.color = '';
                                    this.getWholeDictionaryList(prop.dictionaryId.value, prop)
                                }
                            });
                        });
              
                    }
                    component.hideLoader();
                });
        },
        getWholeDictionaryList(dictionaryId: number, prop: any){
            this.$store.dispatch('dictionaries/getWholeDictionaryList', dictionaryId).then(
                ({ data, status }: { data: Array<any> |string , status: number })  => {
                if (status === 500) {
                    this.$message({
                        message: data as string,
                        type: "error"
                    });
                } else {
                    const arrData = data as Array<any>;
                    arrData.map((item,index) => {
                        prop.dictionaryList = [];
                        prop.dictionaryList = data;                 
                        this.getDictionaryItemColor(item.id.value, data, index, prop);
                    });
                }
            });
        },
        getDictionaryItemColor(dictionaryItemId:number, dictionaryList: Array<any>, index:number, current){
            this.$store.dispatch('patterns/getDictionaryItemColor', dictionaryItemId).then((data: any, status: number) => {
                if (status === 500) {
                    this.$message({
                        message: data as string,
                        type: "error"
                    });
                } else{
                    debugger
                    if(current.dictionaryItemId.value === data.data.sceneObjectId)
                    current.color = data.data.colorString;
                     dictionaryList[index].color = data.data.colorString ? data.data.colorString: '#FFFFFF';

                }
            });
        },
```

Html code of the select box

```
  <el-select v-model="data.color" placeholder="Select">
    <el-option
      v-for="item in data.dictionaryList"
      :key="item.name"
      :label="item.color"
      :value="item.color">
    </el-option>
  </el-select>
```

Comment: It's unclear where are you storing the colors: is it in your store? Or in the component itself? Chances are, you are using promises but are not waiting for them to resolve, which results in a race condition.

Comment: You are using `.map` in multiple places, and inside the map you are trying to mutate the data. The `.map` method doesn't change the items during a loop. It returns a new list, try doing something like this:

```arrData = arrData.map((item,index) => {...})```

Comment: Terry - the colors are coming from the backend, i'm using then at the end of each call

Comment: i will try to use foreach

Comment: yes, `forEach` works better here @VadimTomashevsky

Comment: not working :( with the foreach , i can see the data in console log but it showing that the select box is empty at the html select box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did return to dispatch

```
let dispatch = this.getWholeDictionaryList(prop.dictionaryId.value, prop)
let promiseArr = [];
```

promiseArr.push(dispatch);
after the map closing tag i did

```
Promise.all(promisArr).then( () => {
                                        debugger
                                        this.$data.propertiesTree = anyData;
                                    });
```

And I've got it solved